# how can @Max @Min @Valid works? in java

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

We commonly used validation check by @Valid, @Max, @Min, etc. I wonder how those work.

When some object is created, with some validation annotation (@Max)
how can it inject code that object with annotation (@Max) is not valid or invalid?

I made @GetMapping annotation for studying purposes (with out using implements ConstraintValidator) and was easy, but how I can make @Max annotation for studying purposes?

Comment: Give a look at this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: @Joshgun that was the way making validation annotation.
I wondered.. who is in charge of checking validation. and how it's implemented when object creation valid check.

Comment: Yes, and as you've asked "how I can make @Max annotation for studying purposes", that resource explains how you can create your own validator annotation.

Comment: An annotation by itself does nothing, just record information. It is the bean-validation implementation (e.g. Hibernate Validator) that does the actual validation.